# bluetooth problem after upgrade from ubuntu 14 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, bluetooth

after upgrade to ubuntu 16.04 i can't turn on bluetooth on my laptop .
try reinstall bluez and other bluetooth application same as blueman and bluetooth but don't solve problem

service bluetooth status

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2016-05-15 10:14:59 IRDT; 5h 40min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1104 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1104 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 15 10:15:03 morteza-CX61-2PC bluetoothd[1104]: Not enough free handles to register service
May 15 10:15:03 morteza-CX61-2PC bluetoothd[1104]: Not enough free handles to register service
May 15 10:15:03 morteza-CX61-2PC bluetoothd[1104]: Sap driver initialization failed.
May 15 10:15:03 morteza-CX61-2PC bluetoothd[1104]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
May 15 10:15:04 morteza-CX61-2PC bluetoothd[1104]: Loading LTKs timed out for hci0
May 15 10:15:41 morteza-CX61-2PC bluetoothd[1104]: Failed to set mode: Not Powered (0x0f)
May 15 10:15:41 morteza-CX61-2PC bluetoothd[1104]: Failed to get connections: Not Powered (0x0f)
May 15 10:16:52 morteza-CX61-2PC bluetoothd[1104]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
May 15 10:17:02 morteza-CX61-2PC bluetoothd[1104]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
May 15 14:13:45 morteza-CX61-2PC bluetoothd[1104]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
```

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:3394 IMC Networks Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

rfkill list

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

when i go to setting and choose bluetooth show "no bluetooth found"
screenshot : http://storage6.static.itmages.com/i/16/0515/h_1463312053_7827113_7a4e2df260.png

dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

```
[    0.147244] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.816454] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    1.761166] usb 3-7: Product: RT Bluetooth Radio
[    1.776032] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 3 (with firmware version 0x550f00)
[   15.773162] Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723fw_B.bin
[   18.901441] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   18.901451] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   18.901454] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   18.901455] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   18.901459] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   19.093565] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200
[   19.093568] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
[   40.996583] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   40.996585] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   40.996588] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   41.247665] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   41.247670] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   41.247673] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   42.998956] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c56 tx timeout
[  102.826854] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff8800c6322d80 failed to resubmit (113)
[  112.790161] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff8800a66bf240 failed to resubmit (113)
```

when i try search device in blueman software receive this error

```
Resource Not Ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 146, in warp
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/Adapter.py", line 135, in start_discovery
    self.get_interface().StartDiscovery()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.bluez.Error.NotReady: Resource Not Ready

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/blueman-manager", line 210, in inquiry
    self.List.DiscoverDevices()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py", line 401, in DiscoverDevices
    self.Adapter.start_discovery()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 148, in warp
    raise parse_dbus_error(exception)
blueman.bluez.errors.DBusNotReadyError: Resource Not Ready
```

when i trye to restart bluetooth service from terminal popup error message with this content

```
Connection to BlueZ failed
Bluez daemon is not running, blueman-manager cannot continue.
This probably means that there were no Bluetooth adapters detected or Bluetooth daemon was not started.
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: Please file a [bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) against package Linux as I don't think this bluetooth has worked since the code was added to the kernel

Comment: thanks i try report bug but don't success beacuse my problam hasn't any crash or software message , update my post with new error on bluman software  end of my post

Comment: [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1011078) is a better explanation, start with `ubuntu-bug linux`

Comment: thank's , now i cant do any thing to solve this problem ? i need bluetooth on my device

Comment: this happens to me after suspend. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387211

Comment: Still happens randomly on Arch as well. looks like Bluetooth sucks overall in linux

Answer (score 0):

You could try to reinstall bluetooth:

```
sudo apt-get purge bluetooth
sudo apt-get install bluetooth
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, in my case i purged and reinstalled all these which solved the problem: `sudo apt remove blueman bluez bluetooth`, and then `sudo apt install blueman bluez bluetooth`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me (from cold boot)

```
sudo hciconfig -a hci0
sudo hciconfig hci0 down
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hciconfig -a hci0
```

Looks like xenial and ubuntu bluetooth sucks (at least compared to windows setup for my wife).

I still have bluetooth disconnect from the headphones < 1 meter away from laptop using HP 17 after 30seconds to 2 minutes. No other devices have this problem, but I have changed the m-pci-e card twice now to two different hardware boards both have the same issues.

Comment: When I got to the third command, I get:
% sudo hciconfig hci0 up  <br>
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)

Comment: I don't know if the % is a notation or something mistyped, but I'd suggest looking at your firmware etc if a device cannot be loaded

Comment: % is the standard shell command prompt notation used to distinguish commands from command output, but of course we can't format code in comments on StackExchange, so it's hard to parse. I'll dig into your suggestion, thanks for responding.